# ACTION_UP is not working, but ACTION_DOWN works fine

Tags: java, android, android-studio, event-handling, eventhandler

I've been learning (slowly) how to program Android games using Java and Android Studio. My main source of learning was following the tutorials that are located on the [Kilobolt Tutorial Website](http://www.kilobolt.com/game-development-tutorial.html). I have found these extremely helpful, but because they are tutorials on Android ADT for Eclipse, and they are 3 years old, I have had to do a lot learning with each section to learn Android Studio (a huge process).

I have found that, mostly, that the logic on the tutorial has been solid.
My issue is that in the SingleTouchHandler class of the framework provided by Kilobolt, ACTION_UP does not seem to work. Here is the Input Class:

```
public interface Input {

public static class TouchEvent {
    public static final int TOUCH_DOWN = 0;
    public static final int TOUCH_UP = 1;
    public static final int TOUCH_DRAGGED = 2;
    public static final int TOUCH_HOLD = 3;

    public int type;
    public int x, y;
    public int pointer;

}

public boolean isTouchDown(int pointer);

public int getTouchX(int pointer);

public int getTouchY(int pointer);

public List<TouchEvent> getTouchEvents();

}
```

and here is it's implementation:

```
public class SingleTouchHandler implements TouchHandler {
boolean isTouched;
int touchX;
int touchY;
Pool<TouchEvent> touchEventPool;
List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = new ArrayList<TouchEvent>();
List<TouchEvent> touchEventsBuffer = new ArrayList<TouchEvent>();
float scaleX;
float scaleY;

public SingleTouchHandler(View view, float scaleX, float scaleY) {
    PoolObjectFactory<TouchEvent> factory = new PoolObjectFactory<TouchEvent>() {
        @Override
        public TouchEvent createObject() {
            return new TouchEvent();
        }
    };
    touchEventPool = new Pool<TouchEvent>(factory, 100);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);

    this.scaleX = scaleX;
    this.scaleY = scaleY;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    synchronized(this) {
        TouchEvent touchEvent = touchEventPool.newObject();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN;
                isTouched = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_DRAGGED;
                isTouched = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP;
                isTouched = false;
                break;
        }

        touchEvent.x = touchX = (int)(event.getX() * scaleX);
        touchEvent.y = touchY = (int)(event.getY() * scaleY);
        touchEventsBuffer.add(touchEvent);

        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isTouchDown(int pointer) {
    synchronized(this) {
        if(pointer == 0)
            return isTouched;
        else
            return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int getTouchX(int pointer) {
    synchronized(this) {
        return touchX;
    }
}

@Override
public int getTouchY(int pointer) {
    synchronized(this) {
        return touchY;
    }
}

@Override
public List<TouchEvent> getTouchEvents() {
    synchronized(this) {
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
            touchEventPool.free(touchEvents.get(i));
        touchEvents.clear();
        touchEvents.addAll(touchEventsBuffer);
        touchEventsBuffer.clear();
        return touchEvents;
    }
}
}
```

Again, these are a framework provided by the good man James Cho from Kilobolt and readily available on the Kilobolt website if wanted.

In my implementation: TOUCH_DOWN, a variable used to represent any ACTION_DOWN usage, work fine. However, TOUCH_UP (for ACTION_UP) doesn't work at all.  Here is a block of code where I use it in my games Update Function:

```
    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = (TouchEvent) touchEvents.get(i);
        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {



        }

        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
            if (inBounds(event, 190, 350, 100, 100)) {

                game.setScreen(new Menu(game));
            }
        }
    }
```

In my code above, when the touch is lifted off the screen, TOUCH_UP should allow my game state to change to the Menu Screen. However, nothing happens.

If I placed `game.setScreen(new Menu(game));` in the if statement:

`if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN)` it works fine.

Is it an error in the code or do I have a misunderstanding of how ACTION_UP and the other actions work? I test using a Samsung Galaxy S5.

Thanks for any help. Learning Android Studio and game development has been one heck of a process, but I'm definitely getting better.

Comment: I'm kind of curious why you're doing this at all.  You're doing a lot of work to provide an API very much like already exists, and missing important details (like the difference between cancel and up) in doing so.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan could you elaborate or provide me a resource to read up on? I'm I would like to know. Like I said, I'm extremely new to Android Programming and Android Studio in general (but somewhat school in Java). I am open to anything and want to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably returning `false` on `ACTION_DOWN`.

`ACTION_UP` only works when you return `true` on your `ACTION_DOWN` event.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be reinventing the wheel here. Have you tried a simpler approach?

Firstly, implement the actual listeners, like View.OnTouchListener. It's simple, was introduced in API level 1, and works perfectly.

In fact, I wouldn't even have a SingleTouchHandler class (unless of course you plan on setting this touch listener on multiple views. In this case, implement OnTouchListener instead of TouchHandler). I would simply initialize the onTouch method within the constructor of an OnTouchListener, like so:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        //Synchronize if you wish
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //Press code
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //Move code
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //release code
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

No need for any extra classes at all. Simply include this in the constructor of your subclass of View. This has been tested and works as expected on SurfaceViews which, if you're coding dynamic games, you should be using anyways. Secondly, as stated, if you wish to set this OnTouchListener on multiple views, then you will need to make it it's own class, like the one you already have (SingleTouchHandler) and make it implement View.OnTouchListener (not TouchHandler). However, again, assuming you're programming dynamic games, all graphics will most likely be drawn on one SurfaceView, meaning that there would be only one View on which to assign this OnTouchListener, eliminating the need for a class all together (use the approach shown above).

Comment: I am probably going to sound very naive but I am trying to understand this well, would I place the code you have above in my TouchHandler class, or would it be an extra method within my GameScreen class?

Comment: It should be placed in the constructor of your GameScreen class (or whatever method assigns it a view). Basically, assuming GameScreen extends some sort of View, right after you initialize it, call the above code.

Comment: I've realized where I'm confused,  I'm not sure where my game class is creating the view. I have a class named AndroidFastRenderView that I believe handles the view for the entire game and all its different screens/state, so I wonder if  it belongs there.